# How to get .apk icon path from it's resourceId?

Tags: android, node.js, icons, apk

I'm using a nodeJS module to extract informations about an android .apk file, and among the informations i get is the icon's resourceId:

```
icon: 'resourceId:0x7f0f0000'
```

How do i find the precise path to the icon file(s) within the .apk using this resource ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aapt2's dump command, i.e.

```
aapt2 dump resources base.apk
```